# Ext in Dedekind domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

I know and can prove that $\operatorname{Ext}_Z^1(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z},A) \simeq A/pA$. Does similar formula work for more general rings, such as Dedekind domains and their ideals, i.e. $\operatorname{Ext}_R^1(R/I,M) \simeq M/IM$ ? It seems that the original proof needs the principality of ideals, but I am unable to prove it otherwise or to find some counterexample.

Comment: I got some very nice answers and examples regarding this question on mathoverflow: [link](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/104300/ext-of-cyclic-module).